# how to get data from form to redirect SimpleForm edit

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have a react component below. and I want to redirect with the dataset response from dataset_id. How to i get the data to put into the redirect field for simple form ?

```
export const qnaEdit = props => {
    return (
    <Edit {...props}>
        <SimpleForm

        redirect="data_sets">
            <TextInput disabled source="id" />
            <TextInput datasetid="dataset_id" />
            <TextInput source="question" />
            <TextInput multiline source="short_answer" />
            {/* <RichTextField multiline source="url" /> */}
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);}
```

Comment: Are you trying to redirect only on save?

Answer (score 2):

RedirectTo  can be a function, not only string, so it should help.

```
if (typeof redirectTo === 'function') {
    return redirectTo(basePath, id, data);
}
```

https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-core/src/util/resolveRedirectTo.ts

**Documentation:** https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#redirection-after-submission

You can also pass a custom route (e.g. “/home”) or a function as redirect prop value. For example, if you want to redirect to a page related to the current object:

```
// redirect to the related Author show page
const redirect = (basePath, id, data) => `/author/${data.author_id}/show`;

export const PostEdit = (props) => {
    <Edit {...props}>
        <SimpleForm redirect={redirect}>
            ...
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);
This affects both
```